# My mac encounters lots of internet usage?

Tags: networking, mac, network-monitoring, network-traffic

My macbook is consuming lots of internet data, but usually my work needs nearly 1 or 2 GB but it consumes 8 to 10 GB of internet data, I don't know which app is using internet in background. I can't find that, tried so many ways.. I am using VPN for my work, in activity monitor its just showing process sslvpnd. Installed wireshark too, but Don't know how to find which app is using lots of data in background, If I find that, If I really don't want I can disable it.

If anybody had experience in my issue, kindly help me to resolve that

Comment: Does this also happen if the VPN is disabled?

Comment: @Robert, No Its only happen when VPN is connected

Comment: VPNs will naturally use extra bandwidth compared to your "normal" usage but it should be relatively minor, of the order of 10-20% more due to extra protocol overhead and encryption. Otherwise there may me more "keep alive" data or other data being sent between your VPN provider and your computer. If this is a corporate VPN then you should speak to your IT people, otherwise you would need to tell us what you are actually doing and who the provider is.

Comment: Is there any way to find usage stats app wise? Like this app is using this much data

Comment: [This question](https://superuser.com/questions/1216633/shouldnt-all-of-my-network-traffic-be-going-through-my-vpn-client-why-do-appli) suggests the tool "Little Snitch" might be of use...